# "Red frame" around the screen when starting some apps

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, nexus-7, z4root

Just recently I noticed on my Nexus 7 that when I start some apps - and it's not just those allows to have superuser rights - I can briefly see a "red frame" all around the screen area of the app that goes away in a second or maybe a little less.

Does anyone know where this comes from and in particular what it means?

Note: as you probably guessed from the contents, my device is rooted. Also note that it's well possible that one of the installed apps is responsible for this, yet I don;t know which. But I'd like to know.

Comment: That sounds vaguely like the developer options -- check to see if you've got those enabled.

Comment: @offby1: spot on. Please write it as an answer and I will accept it. Although I cannot tell which exact option caused this, disabling the developer options altogether fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Xposed framework did this on my device. Disabling strict mode in developer options didnt work. Disabling Xposed framework worked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is caused by the strict mode setting under the developer options. It flashes a red border around the screen when anything does a long operation on the main thread.

Answer (score 5):

Happened with me also. Uncheck the strict mode setting and then reboot the device. Dont forget to reboot.otherwise the settings' change wont apply.

Comment: It's unnecessary to reboot the device. I've toggled this setting many times. It takes effect immediately.

Comment: It may be neccessary. On my Fairphone with Android 4.2.2 it was only disabled after a reboot.

Comment: A reboot was necessary on my Samsung Note Pro.

Comment: @scott severance : On my phone(MI4i), a reboot was necessary for the setting change to take effect.